# Update ObjectId while saving another object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Am trying to update the the objectId of a foreign key in my schema after saving

```
   router.post('/add/:id', (req,res)=>{
    const newMenu = new Menu()
    newMenu.menu_name = req.body.menu_name

    const restaurantId = req.params.id

    Menu.addNewMenu(newMenu, (err, menu)=>{
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.json({status: false, err: err})
      }else {
        Restaurant.findRestById(restaurantId,(err,restaurant)=>{
          restaurant.update({
            $push: {menus: menu._id}
          })
          restaurant.save((err,rest)=>{
            res.json({status: true})
          })
        })
      }
    })
  })
```

But after this `menus` array doesn't get updated

this is my `Menu` Schema

```
    const MenuSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  menu_name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  items:[
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Item'
    }
  ]
})
```

And `Restaurant` Schema

```
    const RestaurantSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  rest_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  opening_period:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  image_url:{
    type:String,
    required: true
  },
  menus:[
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Menu'
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Small remark: you don't need to call `save` after `update` as the latter should save the document.

Comment: Oh but with that it did not work still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simply

```
Restaurant.findRestById(restaurantId, (err, restaurant) => {
    restaurant.update({ $push: { menus: menu.id }}, (err) => {
         res.json({ status: true })
    })
})
```

Your `save` could have overwritten the first `update` changes.

Shorter to use [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate).

Comment: Yes thank you that worked..the save was overwriting the update